# Why is my image not scrollable in Android?

Tags: java, android, scrollable

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image_scroll_id">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/sandwich_picture_content_description"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Does the image extend beyond the bounds of the screen, such that there is anything to actually scroll?

Comment: Um. So. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes

Comment: Please show us the full layout XML file (you may give abbreviations for the non critical parts).

Comment: The height of the image is just 220dp, how can it be longer than the height of the screen to enable scrolling?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`ParralaxScroll`](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll).

Comment: @ReazMurshed maybe. new to android can u give me a sample?

Comment: It will scroll only when content of layout is larger than screen. In other cases it will stay as it is. If you want to scroll the content you need to add more content to your view.

Comment: You need to add more content inside linearlayout of scrollview, only then it will become scrollable and if you have a content like in above pic then it cannot be scrolled as it fits the screen of device.